# Apply a function to a View

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working in SQL 2012. I used to use a cross apply command on a single table view on SQL 2008 R2. I'm doing a multiple table view and trying to use the cross apply and I am receiving an error. I'm not sure if the join is causing the issue or if it's related to the CROSS APPLY.

Here is what used to work:

```
    CREATE VIEW [dbo].[AttributeValues_VW]
    AS 
    select userProfileID, Name, Item
    from dbo.AttributeValues
    cross apply dbo.udf_Split(Value,',') as Item;

    GO
```

Here is what I am trying:

```
    Create View [dbo].[DistrictManager_VW] AS
    Select Distinct AV.UserProfileID, AV.Name, AV.Value, UP.EmailAddress, MR.RoleID 
    From Mup_UserAttributeValue AV
    Join Mup_UserProfile UP on AV.UserProfileID=UP.UserProfileID
    Join Mup_Role MR on MR.UserProfileID=AV.UserProfileID
    Join Main_Form MF on MF.[Primary Email]=UP.EmailAddress
    Where RoleID=267

    cross apply dbo.udf_Split(AV.Value,',') as Item;

    Go
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cross apply` goes in the `from` clause:

```
Create View [dbo].[DistrictManager_VW] AS
    Select Distinct AV.UserProfileID, AV.Name, AV.Value, UP.EmailAddress, MR.RoleID 
    From Mup_UserAttributeValue AV Join
         Mup_UserProfile UP
         on AV.UserProfileID = UP.UserProfileID Join
         Mup_Role MR
         on MR.UserProfileID = AV.UserProfileID Join
         Main_Form MF
         on MF.[Primary Email] = UP.EmailAddress
         cross apply dbo.udf_Split(AV.Value, ',') as Item;
    Where RoleID = 267;
```

However, you don't seem to be using `Item`.  Should that be in the `select` clause.

Comment: Oh, excellent, thank you, I tried using different placement but I didn't put it this way. Thank you so much! I will look at the Item bit now. Mostly, I wanted to figure out how I needed to get a multi-join with function going :)